# Laravel pagination to json

Tags: laravel-4, pagination

I am trying to return paginated results in an AJAX call.
In my search i found [Laravel 4.1 API Pagination - Create a custom JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692619/laravel-4-1-api-pagination-create-a-custom-json-response/23695667#comment39933190_23695667)

I tryed it but i cant fix it. The answer offers the following code:

```
$products = Product::paginate(100);
$response = [
 'products'   => $products->getItems()->toArray(),
 'pagination' => [
     'total'        => $products->getTotal(),
     'per_page'     => $products->getPerPage(),
     'current_page' => $products->getCurrentPage(),
     'last_page'    => $products->getLastPage(),
     'from'         => $products->getFrom(),
     'to'           => $products->getTo()
 ]
];
```

I changed it to

```
$myList = $myTable->paginate(10);
$response = array(
    'products'   => $myList->getItems()->toArray(),
    'pagination' => array(
        'total'        => $myList->getTotal(),
        'per_page'     => $myList->getPerPage(),
        'current_page' => $myList->getCurrentPage(),
        'last_page'    => $myList->getLastPage(),
        'from'         => $myList->getFrom(),
        'to'           => $myList->getTo()
    )
);
```

but I get an error on $myList->getItems()->toArray()

```
Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object
```

i changed it to

```
$myList->toArray()
```

for testing purposes which returns

```
{"products":
 {"total":2,"per_page":10,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"from":1,"to":2,
  "data":[{"id":41,"naam":"aqua 1","series_id":99,"stijlen_id":2,"kleuren_id":13,"datum":"2013-06-21 14:58:21","prijzen_id":1,"weergaven":21,"designers_id":0,"omschrijving":"geen omschrijving beschikbaar","video":"","img":"BetteAqua.jpg"},{"id":26,"naam":"one","series_id":100,"stijlen_id":2,"kleuren_id":13,"datum":"2013-06-21 13:40:09","prijzen_id":1,"weergaven":12,"designers_id":0,"omschrijving":"geen omschrijving beschikbaar","video":"","img":"BetteOne_2.png"}]},"pagination":{"total":2,"per_page":10,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"from":1,"to":2}}
```

Here i found that the variable is called data so i tryed

```
$myList->data->toArray()
```

But that doesnt work either. How can i return the 'items' in the products array ?

edit:

The results are returned with :

```
return Response::json($response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `getItems()` already returns an `array` (see [the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php#L385)).

To get just the `data`, try:

```
'products' => $myList->toArray()['data']
```

Comment: Tryed it, it returns {"products":[{"timestamps":false,"incrementing":true,"exists":true},{"timestamps":false,"incrementing":true,"exists":true}],"pagination":{"total":2,"per_page":10,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"from":1,"to":2}} , notice how there is much less data in products array

Comment: Right, that doesn't get the data. Try `'products' => $myList->toArray()['data']`.